# How to select video in windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am building an app in which user can send video captured by him to azure database and later on it can be fetched from their but I am not able to select video like wise we have photochoosertask for images can any body help me with this also this app will also be sending recordings so if any body can tell how it can be sent then it will be a great help.

Comment: Using punctuation here would help your readers help you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `FileOpenPicker` control in XAML?

Refer here fore more:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871377.aspx

Hope it helps!